# Application of High-level Mathematics to Hashing

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Sorry if this post is a tad unconventional(it's also a reddit repost), but I was recently commissioned by a teacher to write a paper on the application of high-level math to a topic of our choice, and, being familiar with basic cryptography, I chose to explore hash collisions. The prompt was extremely broad and ultimately amounted to "summarize the application of high-level math to a topic of your choice". As of now, I have summarized the equation for determining the likelihood of hash collision given the number of output values. However, I am still well under the word count.

What other topics can you suggest?

Preferably, this would relate to some form of calculus, differential equations, linear algebra, high-level probability, or anything reasonably high-level. Thanks for whatever help you can provide.

Comment: Not calculus, nor differential equations, certainly... It uses Linear algebra, number theory, probability, group theory. But this is an unsuitable question for this site in its current form. Too broad. Homework is also off topic usually unless you show your efforts.

Comment: Any linear algebra you can link to?

Comment: There is the xsl attack that uses large numbers of simultaneous equations. It's for block ciphers, but you may be able to find a derivative for hashes.

Comment: Could you link to the xsl?

Comment: You won't believe me, but for daft reasons I actually can't.  There's a wiki page - "xsl attack" :-)

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - About your question: since we are a question and answer site rather than a forum, "what topics can you suggest" is not really an appropriate question format for our site. We require questions that can be objectively answered rather than subjectively discussed. A question like "How is probability related to hashing and collisions" would be a great example of an objectively answerable question. We have to close this one; If/when you acquire enough reputation points, you can ask open-ended questions in the sites [chat room](https://tinyurl.com/y4862mv8)

Comment: @PaulUszak The XSL attack isn't considered a realistic attack.

Comment: I came across this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/295.pdf) relating to linearisation of hashes.